# Java game character moving too fast

Tags: java

So I'm working on this java 2d game for fun. Someone on youtube was doing it and I'm just following his tutorial. The problem is that when I try and move my character it sprints across the screen. I have my setVelX value to -1 but it moves a lot more than that. I've tried making the input movement speed to a double but if it goes to a double he just never moves.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    for(entity en: Game.handler.entity)
    {
    switch(key){
    case KeyEvent.VK_W:
        if (en.jumping==false)
        {
            en.jumping = true;
            en.gravity = 10.0;
        }
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_S:
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
        en.setVelX(-1);
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_D:
        en.setVelX(1);
        break;
    }
    }
```

mostly focusing on the A or D to try and get the speed to slow down

```
public void setVelX(double velX) {
    this.velX = velX;
}



public void tick() {
    x+=velX;


 while (running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+=(now-lastTime)/1000000000;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1)
            { 
                tick();
                ticks++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis()-timer>1000)
            {
                timer+=1000;
                System.out.println(frames + " FPS " + ticks + " Updates/sec");
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }
```

I've looked through other questions like this but I can not find anything that helps. The character moves a lot more than the 1 space and the animation of the character is very fast as well.

Comment: You should think in terms of # of frames rendered per second and gait your loop with a Thread.sleep so that it renders on a consistent timeslice.  Otherwise, like you're seeing, the speed of the character will vary from device to device because of processing speed differences between the devices.

Comment: Please, don't just follow any YT tutorial without knowing what exactly the code does. If you don't know Java, go and learn Java properly. If you know Java, first try to use debug outputs. In your case, you apparently never reset `velX`, which is why the speed at which your character moves increases more and more - and that very fast. Using debug outputs, you probably could've figured that out without asking here

Comment: you are calling tick inside tick?? and whats that supposed to do?? any more clever tricks?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should reset the velocity, because when you add it every time he would move really fast (25 FPS=25 Moves), and I suggest you to use Thread sleep for only 25 FPS, else every frame this operations would be done, and that would mean that everything happens lot faster so that it appears that he moves much more than that. Code :

```
 try {
 Thread.sleep(33); //FPS 25
 } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
 System.out.println(bug);
 }
```

and, in void tick :

```
 VelX=0;
```

to reset the velocity.

But currently Im developing a java game of the same type too, and so I have a "**tutorial**" for you :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

class Player {
     public float health;
     public float yvel;
     public float xvel;
     public float x;
     public float y;
     public BufferedImage image;
     public void work(Graphics g, int[] keys) {
         g.drawImage(image,(int)x,(int)y,null);
         if (keys[0]==1) { //Is the UP-Key pressed
             yvel=yvel-1;
         }
         if (keys[1]==1) { //Is the DOWN-Key pressed
             yvel=yvel+1;
         }
         if (keys[2]==1) { //Is the LEFT-Key pressed
             xvel=xvel-1;
         }
         if (keys[3]==1) { //Is the RIGHT-Key pressed
             xvel=xvel+1;
         }
         x=x+xvel;
         y=y+yvel;
         xvel=xvel-(xvel/4); //One fourth gets lost
         yvel=yvel-(yvel/4); //One fourth gets lost
     }

     public Player(BufferedImage imagew,float xw, float yw, float healthw) {
         x=xw;
         y=yw;
         image=imagew;
         health=healthw;
     }
}
public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
     public BufferedImage playerimage;
     public Player player;
     public int[] keys=new int[4];

     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                 keys[0]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                 keys[1]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                 keys[2]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                 keys[3]=1;
             }
     }
     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                 keys[0]=0;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                 keys[1]=0;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                 keys[2]=0;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                 keys[3]=0;
             }
     }
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                 keys[0]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                 keys[1]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                 keys[2]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                 keys[3]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                 keys[4]=1;
             }
     } 
     public Game(){
          super("Game");
          try {
          playerimage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("player.gif")); //Player Image
          } catch(IOException bug) {
          System.out.println(bug);
          }

          player=new Player(playerimage,100,100,100);

          addKeyListener(this);

          setTitle("Game");

          setContentPane(new Pane());

          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          setSize(800, 600);

          setResizable(false);

          setVisible(true); 

          while (true){
              repaint();
              try {
              Thread.sleep(33);
              } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              System.out.println(bug);
              }
          }
     }


     class Pane extends JPanel{
        public Pane() {
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            player.work(g,keys);
        }   
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
            new Game();
     }
}
```

This works fine and because always only a fourth gets lost as **friction**, it really "glides" over the screen.

Here is the graph for the friction : The speeds gradient is very low.

[image: Friction Graph : You can see that the speeds gradient is very low.]